# How to compare keys and values of dictionaries in a 2 different list and print mismatched keys and values

Tags: python

I have two lists my aim is to compare list_two with list_one and print the difference

```
list_one = [{'name': 'xyz', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'pqr', 'age': 50},
            {'name': 'abc', 'age': 30}]
list_two = [{'name': 'xyz', 'age': 25, 'hair_color': 'brown'},
            {'name': 'pqr', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black'},
            {'name': 'lmn', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black'}]
```

Expected Output:

```
{'Output': [{'name': 'xyz', 'age': 25, 'Status': 'Match'},
            {'name': 'pqr', 'age': 30, 'Status': 'age mismatch', 'Expected_age':'50'},
            {'name': 'lmn', 'age': 30, 'Status': 'total mismatch'}]}
```

I tried with below code to get Expected Output, but didn’t get it::

```
listOne = list_one
listTwo = list_two    
listKey = []
listValues = []
for x in listOne:
    listKey.append(x['name'])
    listValues.append(x['age'])
    output_comp={}
    output_comp['Output']=[]
    for i in listTwo:
        if i['name'] in listKey:
            if i['age'] in listValues:
                output_comp['Output'].append({'name': i['name'],
                                              'age': i['age'],
                                              'Status': 'Match'})
            else:
                output_comp['Output'].append({'name': i['name'],
                                              'age':i['age'],
                                              'Status':'age mismatch',
                                              'Expected_age': x['age']})
        else:output_comp['Output'].append({'name': i['name'],
                                           'age': i['age'],
                                           'Status': 'total mismatch'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have make a simple loop that kinda does what you want, but because I have to go somewhere now so I can't finish it. So it gets the dict that are mismatched and tells you what is wrong with it I only didn't implement the "matched" part of it but you can play with it and figure out how to do that, also  I haven't tested it for multiple "wrong" values

Here is the code

```py
list_one = [{'name': 'xyz', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'pqr', 'age': 50},
            {'name': 'abc', 'age': 30}]
list_two = [{'name': 'xyz', 'age': 25, 'hair_color': 'brown'},
            {'name': 'pqr', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black'},
            {'name': 'lmn', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black'}]

wrongList = []
line = 0

for value in list_one:
    value = value.items()
    checkvalue = list_two[line]
    line += 1

    for k,v in value:
        if(v != checkvalue[k]):
            checkvalue["Mismatch"] = k
            checkvalue["Expected"] = v
            wrongList.append(checkvalue)

print(wrongList)
```

Output: `[{'name': 'pqr', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black', 'Mismatch': 'age', 'Expected': 50}, {'name': 'lmn', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black', 'Mismatch': 'name', 'Expected': 'abc'}]`